# What is the single word that describes a person who always gossips?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

What is the single word that describes a person who always gossips? (For example, telling things about others which are not true.)

Comment: You should note that gossip is not always false.

Comment: @Theta30 that's assuming you know that *gossiper* is a valid noun; if OP had, s/he presumably wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: Are you looking for a noun or an adjective?

Answer (score 27):

Er... perhaps a *[gossip](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gossip)*? You may also see *gossipmonger* and *gossiper*, but in US English just plain old *gossip* is the standard noun.

Comment: And also in the UK.

Comment: Wonder why the hesitation and the '*perhaps*'! Any reservations?

Comment: The *perhaps* was a bit ironic, as the answer was contained in the question itself.

Answer (score 5):

As [onomatomaniak](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/52973/77227) said, a person who habitually spreads rumors or engages in indiscreet talk (ie. gossips) can be referred to as a gossip. One thing to note, this would be independent of whether the things he or she tells are true or not.

Alternatively, you could also describe such a person as a rumourmonger, or even a scandalmonger, depending on the nature of the gossip and the intent.

Answer (score 3):

One might call such a person a *[quidnunc](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/quidnunc)*, although that might be thought somewhat out-of-date nowadays. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quidnunc) suggests *quidnunc* is more likely to be someone keen on hearing the latest gossip than repeating it, but I have never met anyone who just listened to scandal and rumour without passing it on.

Answer (score 2):

> **Taleteller:** One who tells tales or stories, especially in a mischievous or officious manner; a talebearer; a telltale; a tattler.
>
> **Slanderer:**  One who makes false and injurious statements about another, one who slanders, one who defames, one who maligns.
>
> **Backbiter:** One who slanders, calumniates, or speaks ill of the absent; person who says nasty things about another person behind the
>   second person's back: that is, out of sight and hearing of the second
>   person.

Comment: I'm confused. This is formatted like a block quotation, but there are three parts that seem distinct, and there isn't any attribution to a source. Is this all in your words, or are these definitions from somewhere else?

Comment: @sumelic: Hi. I looked up those words from online dictionaries but I don't remember their sources (it's been some time).

Answer (score 2):

[Tattletale](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tattletale):

> One who tattles (reports others' wrongdoings), often by a
>   child seeking attention. (Wiktionary)

P.S. You did say that the person always gossips, whether what they say is true or not. The fact that they do it a lot could mean that the person thrives on it, and suggests that it might be child-like, attention-seeking behavior.

Comment: The correct spelling is *tattletale*, or *tattle-tale*, it's an easy one to get wrong, I had to think a bit before I realized. Good suggestion, though. Could you edit your answer, and perhpas include the link which you appeared to have quoted from:  http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tattletale. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*Gossip* should be your top answer but you should consider *blab,* too. It means an incessant or indiscreet talker. Hope that will help you mate.

Comment: I'm in the UK, and I don't think I've ever heard **He is a blab**. But [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+a+blab%2Cis+a+blabbermouth&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) strongly suggests this is primarily British usage. **Blabbermouth**, which sounds completely normal to me, appears to be the dominant American form.

Comment: Well I guess you are right mate, I am just an ordinary not native who has found the word in the dictionary :D I will try to remember blabbermouth - it sounds interesting. Cool nickname, mate.

Answer (score -1):

*Gossip* or *gossiper*. People can also say *blabber* (root word: *blab*).

Comment: Please note that both *gossip* and *gossiper* are both given in the highest voted answer. You might do better to remove those and edit your answer to include an example of how to use *blab* and *blabber*