# Is there a word that describes a person who spreads gossip and false rumours or just simply undermines group relationships?

Tags: single-word-requests, slang

Amongst sailors there is a superstition that assigned the expression "Jonah" to anyone who is considered to bring misfortune or bad luck (Ref. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonah#Jonah_in_sailors.27_superstition).

I would like to know if there is any equivalent slang for a person who intentionally spreads gossip or false rumours, or, let's say, someone who is considered the rotten apple (or black sheep) in a group and normally the one responsible for destabilizing or segregating this group. (I have such person in my family!)

I've already read the article [What is the single word that describes a person who always gossips?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52972/what-is-the-single-word-that-describes-a-person-who-always-gossips) but those expressions don't quite fit my question since i'm looking for a slang or popular expression.

Cheers!

Comment: ... *Big mouth*.

Comment: Here's another: *troublemaker*.

Comment: Rotten apple and black sheep (as already mentioned by you) convey this   sense.

Comment: A gossip.  It's also a noun. Also gossip monger

Comment: A person who is a black sheep is not necessarily bad, just viewed as unacceptable by the rest of the family.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options I can think of.

A ***muckraker** (one who engages in muckraking):

> ***[Muckraking](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/muckraking)***
>   NOUN
>
> *[mass noun]*
>   The action of searching out and publicizing scandal about famous people.
>   *[as modifier] ‘a muckraking journalist’*

And ***busybody***:

> ***[Busybody](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/busybody)***
>   NOUN
>
> A meddling or prying person.
>   *‘others considered him an interfering busybody’*

Neither one really implies *false* rumours, but the former is definitely less savory/more malicious than the latter.

Answer (score 1):

**Scandalmonger** -- "A person who stirs up public outrage towards someone or their actions by spreading rumours or malicious gossip."  [OxfordDictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/scandalmonger)

Comment: also rumormonger

Answer (score 0):

In Eastern Canada at least, someone who stirs up things that most people think would be best ignored may be referred to as a "shit-disturber".

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind a term that relates to more than a single individual but carries the notion you're asking about, consider the term *fifth column* for a *group* of such people working in concert.

The dictionary entry is specific to countries and war, though the cited examples are more general:

> **fifth column** *noun*
>   A group within a country at war who are sympathetic to or working for its enemies.
>   ‘The creation of a potential fifth column within the organization makes the duties of members of the audit committee far more onerous than before, with no relief in sight.’
>   **Origin** The term dates from the Spanish Civil War, when General Mola, leading four columns of troops towards Madrid, declared that he had a fifth column inside the city.
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fifth_column)

The wikipedia entry is more generic:

> A fifth column is any group of people who undermine a larger group from within, usually in favor of an enemy group or nation.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_column)

An individual with a 'fifth column' agenda might be termed a *fifth columnist*.

> **fifth columnist** *countable noun*
>   A fifth columnist is someone who secretly supports and helps the enemies of the country or organization they are in.
>   In my role as fifth columnist I sabotaged her washing line with unsolicited aid and hung washing out with no regard for her conventions. (Attributed to James Birrell THE MANANA MAN (2002))
>   [- Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fifth-columnist)